# How to get the newsletter subscriber box and show the custom Module in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, newsletter, footer, footer-links

I have created the Custom footer page and it is showing fine with 5 columns. Here I want to show the **Newsletter Subscriber box** in my custom `.phtml` file for this I tried to get `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('newsletter'); ?>` and `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscriber'); ?>` But nothing to display here.
For this I have written below code.

**layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
            <!--<referenceBlock name="footer.newsletter" remove="true"/>-->
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="Test_CustomFooter::custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**templates/custom.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var  \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer $block */ ?>
......code.....
<div class="col">
                <h3 class="title">EMail</h3>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('newsletter'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
.......code......
```

So could you please suggest me how to display here..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
            <!--<referenceBlock name="footer.newsletter" remove="true"/>-->
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="Test_CustomFooter::custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>            
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="Test_CustomFooter::custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add below code in phtml file:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscribe'); ?>
```