# How to get newsletter in custom footer in magento 2.2.0?

Tags: layout, newsletter, magento2.2.0

I have a custom-footer in my website. I want to move newsletter to my custom footer. I tried the below code to move but nothing changes.

`move element="form.subscribe" destination="custom_footer"`

Comment: Hera is a solution. you can follow this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148213/how-to-get-the-newsletter-subscriber-box-and-show-the-custom-module-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

If your `custom_footer` element is a block you'll also need to call getChildHtml in your assigned template like so:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Or you can call getChildHtml with the name of the block for more control:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscribe'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure custom footer code should be correct. refer blow:

```
 <referenceContainer name="custom.footer">

 </referenceContainer>

<move element="form.subscribe" destination="custom.footer" before="-" />
```

Comment: I have given the destination name same as the name of container. Now it works but it is not appearing in the div of footer

Comment: Can you please show me your xml code?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <referenceContainer name="custom_footer">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```